# unused number mysql

Tags: php, mysql

How can i get all of the records in a table that are out of
sequence so I know which account numbers I can reuse. I have a range
of account numbers from 50100 to 70100. I need to know which account
numbers are not stored in the table (not currently used) so I can use.

For instance say I have the following data in table:

```
Account Name
------  --------
50100   Test1
50105   Test2
50106   Test4
```

..
..
..
I should see the results:
50101
50102
50103
50104

because 50101-50104 are available account numbers since not currently in
table.

copied from http://bytes.com/topic/sql-server/answers/78426-get-all-unused-numbers-range

With respect to MYSQL and PHP.

EDITED

My range is 10000000-99999999.

My present way is using MySql query:
'SELECT FLOOR(10000000 + RAND() * 89999999) AS random_number FROM contacts WHERE "random_number" NOT IN (SELECT uid FROM contacts) LIMIT 1';

Thanks.

Comment: Why are reusing account numbers? It will have problems in the future as to tracking orders/money/people. Have you reached this limit or close to it? If so add additional digits (or letters)

Comment: i do not have to do monetary tasks only assign number which is available so my best bet is to use any free number,or used and expired due to unsage etc...etc...

Comment: If not money, but it will mess up historical records. (that you may wish to use in the future for statistical analysis). Anyway why put in the effort when you have not used up the numbers?

Comment: yes i did something like this i stored some lakhs of ids in a table, but querying from lakhs of entries during registration is painful.. so i created a small table as an interface between registered users table and all available ids now, i m just querying that interface table to get the ids then removing the selected id from the interface table and its real fast.. also what i did is that setup a cron running every 2  mins and it checks if interface table is runninng below a threshold value of ids then i m refilling the interface table....Thanks to everyone for their ideas...

Comment: WHY are you doing this? THEre is about 7 billion people on this lump of rock. That is 7 followed by 9 zeros - i.e. 10 bytes, uncompressed. Surely your company can spring to a hard drive and save you faffing around?

Comment: but for now Ed the situation demanded me a quick fix for atleast 20lakhs users and after all if users are inactive for 15 days the id is reused.. i wud look forward to you if u cud guide me to a better soln i have will take it .... i had tried and it was my solution....
Any how thx for ur reminder buddy....

Comment: Forgive me ignorance - what is a `lakhs`? Also banks do not seem to have a problem giving out a unique account number - just do the same.

Answer (score 3):

solution 1: 
Generate a table with all possible accountnumbers in it. Then run a query similar to this:

```
SELECT id FROM allIDs WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM accounts)
```

Solution 2: 
Get the whole id colummn into an array in php or java orso. Then run a for-loop to check if the number is in the array.

```
$ids = (array with all ids form the table)
for($i=50100;$i<=70100;$i++){
    if(array_search($i, $ids) != -1){
        $availableids[] = $i;
    }
}
```

Comment: Solution 2 is O(N^2). You should sort the array prior to looking for things, which is O(N log N).

Comment: I opted your solutions Thanks

Answer (score 1):

one way would be to create another table - fill it will all allowable numbers, then write a simple query to find the ones in the new table that are not in the original table.

Answer (score 1):

Sort the accounts in the server, and find jumps in PHP while reading in the results. Any jump in the sorted sequence is "free for use", because they are ordered. You can sort with something like `SELECT AccountNumber FROM Accounts SORT ASCENDING;`.

To improve efficiency, store the free account numbers in another table, and use numbers from this second table until no more remain. This avoids making too many full reads (as in the first paragraph), which may be expensive. While you are at it, you may want to add a hook in the part of the code which deletes accounts, so they are immediately included in this second table, making the first step unnecessary.